# how to detect "hidden files extension" (windows system ) from flash/as3 app?

Tags: actionscript-3, file, save, filereference

i'm working on an app (flash/As3) that lets the user upload and edit an image, and then save it to the computer, 
using FileReference.

it's posible to know if the user computer have the option "hidden file extensions" (windows system) selected? How can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding, no, you cannot do that. It is an OS specific thing.

Why do you even want to know that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will ever want it - the File referencing in AS3 obviously ALWAYS works with extensions, no matter if the Explorer has hidden them - it is just for displaying IN the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to know. When the file is uploaded, you will get the extension whether or not the user has that option enabled in Explorer.

Conversely, when they save the file, you will send it back with the extension, but Explorer will hide it if they have the option turned on.

It shouldn't make a difference to how you code your app.